# Where is the best place to put application-wide logic (notifications) in CakePHP?

Tags: php, performance, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've had a quick search on Stackoverflow but not really found an answer to a question that I have. Sorry if it's already been answered and I've missed it!

I'm working on an application, and similarly to Facebook, there will be 'notifications' but in my case it'll be items that require actions from the user. It would just be a 'count' of the actions that are required and nothing else.

I've followed a fat model, skinny controller approach through my application and so far so good. I have a good idea of what goes where, and when to use a plugin, app model, app controller, etc.

However, I'm a little confused about where to put this notification/action 'count'. I'm guessing either afterFilter() in the app_controller.php file, but that's just a guess. I'm just looking for the most efficient place to put it.

So, where's the best/fastest/most efficient place to put this count call?

Thanks!
Kingsley

**EDIT**: I just realised it's worth pointing out that this particular call is on a model. So, at the moment I have to load that model, and then call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal place is in an [Element](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements).  You can then use [requestAction()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) to tell it where to retrieve it's data from.

The Element is placed into a view (or used to display a Flash message).  Within it, it pulls it's data (requestAction) from a Controller's Action.  That action get's it's data from the Model of your choice just like you would in any other action.  This allows complete separation of concerns (ie MVC).

Comment: Perfect. I didn't think about using requestAction!